# Add new field in checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, backend

I am totally new to Magento. Still learning, so I am confused about where to start off when I have to do something new.

I have to add just another input field in the checkout that gets saved in the order and displayed in the back-end.

So can someone give me directions? It can probably be implemented in an existing extension, but I don’t really have a clue. Any help and explanation will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
For example, I need to take the number of the customer (when he places and order/checks out), save this number and display it in the Order view in the back-end.

What I suppose needs to be done is that I have to fetch this number from the front-end, fire an event which will call a function (from the Observer class) that will set the value of this fetched number into the field in the back-end. But before all that I guess I have to install a script to add this "Customer Number" field in the Order view in the back-end.

Comment: What have you tried so far, any tutorials, code, extensions r something like that? Your question is a bit broad. What should this field do, where do you need it: billing step or review, etc. Please provide some more info to narrow the question down

Comment: @SanderMangel - I updated my post. :)

Comment: Great, I think @KeyurShah already posted some usefull links for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

follow this tutorial it may help you

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page

or

http://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/