# How to add an extra custom validation and field while registration in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to **add a new custom validation** and a **custom field in the checkout process**. When user registers he should be able to add his **username** along with other fields.

The **validation for username** is that it should be contain **min 6 characters**.

(In that is should have **atleast 1 alphabet, 1 number & 1 special character**) .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two think:
First: Validation is done in front by JS - http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/
You can use one predefined or add yourself.

Second:
Validation from backend - Somebody ask how to add field to checkout.

[Add new field in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/add-new-field-in-checkout)

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/

https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/

Tips: It is just added new field in backend. In frontend it is just array of fields so adding one isn't complicated.